# Most succinct way to process this string

Tags: python

I have a string that looks like: "'MAY21: 300 USD/t JUN21: 333 USD/t JUL21: 0 AUG21: 111 USD/t SEP21: 555 USD/t"

From this I wish to obtain :

```
[['MAY21', '300'],
 ['JUN21', '333'],
 ['JUL21', '0'],
 ['AUG21', '111'],
 ['SEP21', '555']]
```

What I can think of involves a few for loops. I would like to know the best way to process this string to obtain the output I desire. The challenge here for me is dealing with, "JUL21: 0 ", which has no USD/t after it.

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regex`

```
import re

a = "MAY21: 300 USD/t JUN21: 333 USD/t JUL21: 0 AUG21: 111 USD/t SEP21: 555 USD/t"

out = re.findall("(\w+): (\d+)",a)

print(out)

    [('MAY21', '300'),
     ('JUN21', '333'),
     ('JUL21', '0'),
     ('AUG21', '111'),
     ('SEP21', '555')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x="MAY21: 300 USD/t JUN21: 333 USD/t JUL21: 0 AUG21: 111 USD/t SEP21: 555 USD/t"
x=x.replace(" USD/t","").replace(": ",":")
x=x.split(" ")
for i in range(len(x)):
  x[i]=x[i].split(":")
```